# Mini computer not booting with USB drive on Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I bought this little computer (link below), but I simply cant make Ubuntu recognize the USB driver in order to install Ubuntu.
It comes with windows 10 which does not recognized the screen of my TV and therefore becomes quite useless.
I know the USB drive I'm using is okay because it boots normally my laptop so.

Anyone can help here?

Thanks for reading and if you know how to solve this would be fantastic!

I already enabled USB legacy support, used boot menu but no luck.

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Mini-PC-Intel-Quad-Core-1-83GHz-Dual-OS-Windows-10-Android-4-4-RAM2GB-ROM32GB-/121969229822?ssPageName=ADME:X:RRNTB:GB:3160

Comment: Try to format the USB with FAT32.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Try a different USB drive or even the microsd port. Ubuntu CAN boot from microsd as well as from USB. You could set up Ubuntu with persistence on the microsd, thus keeping your internal drive intact (not losing Android and Windows).